# The local flatness criterion

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, tensor-products, flatness

I am self studying the book "Commutative Ring Theory" by H. Matsumura. The main theorem of section 22 is the [theorem 22.3](https://books.google.com/books?id=yJwNrABugDEC&pg=PA174), which characterizes flatness of a module $M$ over any ring $A$. The (part of the) theorem states :

Let $A$ be a ring, $I$ an ideal of $A$ and $M$ an $A$-module. Then the following are equivalent

(1) $Tor_1^A(N,M)=0$ for every $A/I$ module $N$;

(2) $M/IM$ is flat over $A/I$ and $I\otimes M =IM$;

(3) $M/IM$ is flat over $A/I$ and $Tor_1^A(A/I,M)=0$.

I have been able to show the above three are equivalent. Furthermore, the theorem also states if one of the above three holds, then one must have :

(4) $M/IM$ is flat over $A/I$ and

$\gamma_n$ : $I^n/I^{(n+1)} \otimes M/IM \rightarrow I^nM/I^{(n+1)}M$ is an isomorphism for all $n\geq 0$.

While proving this, the author of the book uses the result that, if $I\otimes M =IM$ then one must have $I^n\otimes M =I^nM$ for all $n\geq 2$, which I am unable to show. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @A.G Can you explain why? Without one of the assumptions of the theorem, this looks false: take $R=k[x]/(x^2)$, $I=M=(x)$, $J=(1)$. Then $I\otimes M\neq 0$ but $I^2 = 0$. Now if your formula works, we should have $0\neq I\otimes M = (1)\cdot(I\otimes M) = ((1)\cdot I)\otimes M = (I\cdot(1))\otimes M = I\cdot ((1)\otimes M)$. But this is just $I\cdot (R\otimes I) = I^2 = 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Geva Yashfe Yes, I think we need one of the assumptions, or rather loosely speaking, we need flatness. Otherwise, this is not true.

Comment: I'm just hoping to understand what conditions make @A.G 's formula correct, because it looks nice

Comment: @Geva Yashfe In the above example, I\otimes M is indeed 0, right? Because, any generating element of I\otimes M looks like rx\otimes m=r\otimes xm=r\otimes 0=0

Comment: No, this is not the case. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/298198 for instance.

Comment: Yes! My mistake.

Comment: @Geva Yashfe Sorry, my (stupid) mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit: I apologize, the original answer was nonsense (I mixed different Tor functors in a silly way).

The following works, but uses the equivalent condition (1) of the question, and does not show $I\otimes M = IM \implies I^n \otimes M = I^n M$ unconditionally.

Consider the exact sequence:

$$ I^2\otimes M  \rightarrow I \otimes M \rightarrow I/I^2 \otimes M \rightarrow 0.$$

The rightmost module is an $A/I$-module, so $\mathrm{Tor}_1(M, I/I^2)=0$. Hence the first map is injective. Also, $I\otimes M = IM$ and $I/I^2 \otimes M = I \otimes A/I \otimes M$ which by associativity and commutativity of tensor is $IM \otimes A/I = IM/I^2M$. So we have an exact sequence:

$$ 0\rightarrow I^2\otimes M  \rightarrow IM \rightarrow IM/I^2M \rightarrow 0,$$
and $I^2 \otimes M$ is the kernel of the second map, which is $I^2 M$.

It seems this process can be continued: consider the exact sequence

$$ I^3\otimes M  \rightarrow I^2 \otimes M \rightarrow I^2/I^3 \otimes M \rightarrow 0,$$

where again $I^2 / I^3$ is an $A/I$-module and the last two terms are $I^2 M$ and $I^2 M / I^3 M$ respectively; by the vanishing of $\mathrm{Tor}_1(M,N)$ for $N$ an $A/I$-module, the first arrow is an injection and it equals the kernel of the second map, i.e. it is $I^3 M$.

Comment: Thank you! The misleading situation for me was the fact that when one consider a module over the quotient ring $A/I^i$ for some $i>0$, then it naturally becomes $A/I^n$ module for all $n\geq 0$. Then it was very difficult to consider the right exact sequence, and I always believed that, for this problem, considering the right exact sequence is the hey. But your proof is the best way to absorb the full power of the hypothesis. I really thank you for the answer.

Comment: @KkD You are welcome, I enjoyed the question.